# How do I achieve navigating effect within a view in HTML/JS/CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, data-visualization

I wonder how do I make an audience feel like navigating a single page and zoom in/out like the link below.

https://pudding.cool/2017/09/hip-hop-words/

I looked into inspector's css and it uses background-posiiton which I haven't used?
It might have something to do with this attribute I guess?

But not sure what makes the page feel like i'm actually zooming in the page.

before zoom
[image]

after zoom
[image]

Comment: Thanks for showing the cool website. I'm not sure which effect you want to copy as there is a lot going on on this page. I think the background position is not going to be the solution. This is for selecting the different faces from one big image that combines them all: https://pudding.cool/2017/09/hip-hop-words/css/spritesheet.png

Comment: @Hans Dash I added an image to explain the zoom I want to achieve, does this make sense?

Comment: the zoom in the page is happening using `scale` from `css` whereas the background moving is happening with `transform translate`, but `js` is the one changing it dynamically (so whenever the scroll happens it will update the `transform`) and on website the `transform` would look like this `transform: translate3d($[a}px, ${b}px, ${c}px) scale(${d});` where ${a,b,c,d} would be replaced by real numbers..

Comment: @Francisco Thank you so much!! understood!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps: (it does not zoom, but it scrolls the paper so the the clicked portrait is centered)

```js
var portrait = $(".portrait");
var paper = $("#paper");

portrait.click(function(e) {
    var myleft=200-$(this).position().left;
  paper.css({left: myleft})
})
```

```css
#paper {width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid blue; position: absolute; left: 200px;}

.portrait { width: 20px; height: 20px; border: 1px dotted pink; position: relative}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="paper">
  <div class="portrait" style="left: 50px; top: 100px">
  :-)
  </div>
  
    <div class="portrait"  style="left: 200px; top: 100px">
  :-(
  </div>
  
</div>
```